# JQuery method prepend does not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I´ve worked on the text editor and there are one plugin that was created to putting header and footer (basically a row of table) in the editor and one of the business rules is don´t to permit move the header or footer (My version is 3.3.8 but I tested in the last 3.4.6).

I created a method in the basic_config.js, basically inside of the method "ed.onChange.add(function(ed, l)" to readjust the position of header or footer when the user try to move the table to another place, like this:

```
           //find out the div of the header
            var elm = tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.get("testeHeader");

           //case the elm move of position...
           if(elm != null) {
                var txt = tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.getOuterHTML(elm);
                $(elm).remove(); 
                //relocates the header to the top does not works on IE8.
                $('#editor1_ifr').contents().find('body').prepend(txt);**
            }
```

In the Firefox it works but in the Internet Explorer de method prepend fail, nothing happers.

There any solution for this cause?

Thank a bunch for all that get help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work. Give it a try

```
var txt = tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.getOuterHTML(elm);
$(elm).remove(); 
//relocates the header to the top does not works on IE8.
var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
var parent = ed.getBody();
parent.insertBefore( $(txt).get(0), parent.childNodes[0] );
```

Comment: Your Tip is very nice for Firefox ( I have discovered several ways and all ways worked on Firefox ), worked perfectly but nothing happened on IE8. And another occurence is delete instruction that works when I try insert some text but when I have dragging the header and write something on the editor. The delete instruction fail and doesn´t remove. 

There are many difficulties to make things rights on IE. Sorry friend but I was passing for a big torment to that task.